# LINQ filtering list objects

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

I have list object and I need to check id in a comma separated string using LINQ in VB.NET, something like this:

```
dim strId as String = "1,2,3,5,"
dim myList = from objmylist where objmylist.id in (strId)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dim strId as String = "1,2,3,5,"
dim IDs as String() = strId.Split(",")
dim myList = from objmylist where IDs.Contains(objmylist.id) 
             select objmylist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim strId as String = "1,2,3,5,"
dim myList = from objmylist where strId.split(",").Contains(objmylist.id)
```

untested, but should do the trick I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine if you split the string before using it in the linq
In C# you would do this:

```
string strIDs = "1,2,3,5,";
string[] arrIDs = strIDs.Split(",");
var myList = objmylist.Where(o => arrIDs.Contains(o.id));
```

Perhaps you can understand this enough to translate it into VB

Answer (score 0):

Using C#,

```
int[] productList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var myProducts = from p in db.Products
                 where productList.Contains(p.ProductID)
                select p;
```

using VB.NET,

```
Dim productList As Integer() = New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4}

Dim myProducts = From p In db.Products Where productList.Contains(p.ProductID)
```

In Reference from [Creating SQL IN Queries using LINQ](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql)